# JPA ManyToOne query with deleted relation

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.0

I have two entity classes that relate to each other :

```
class Boat {
    public Long boatId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Operation> operations;
}

class Operation {
    public Long operationId;
    @ManyToOne
    public Boat boat;
}
```

These classes are of course related by a table called boat_operation. One of the operations belonging to boat has been removed but the operation still exists.

My data situation is like this :
Operation operationId=1, boat=1
Operation operationId=2, boat=1

Boat boatId=1, operations=1

I wish to write a find method on operation that will find all the operations that can be found in boat.operations ? How can I do this in JPA ?

In SQL it is easy, I use the joining table :
SELECT o.id, o.boat_id
  FROM operationinstance o, boat_operationinstance bo
  WHERE o.id = bo.operations_id and bo.boat_id = o.boat_id ;

Comment: lacking a "mappedBy" in the OneToMany ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I've added the mappedBy because it isn't going to do any harm, but I do not see how it can help ?

Comment: I've also added orphanRemoval but I think I must write a script to remove the unwanted operations that are no longer referenced.

Comment: who said "mappedBy" would _help_? It was needed to correct your mapping, not a case of "not doing any harm". A BIdirectional relation needs mappedBy as all decent JPA docs say

Answer (score 0):

You mean, find all operations for a Boat?

```
SELECT o FROM Operation o WHERE boat = :boat
```

Comment: Sadly, no. I'll give an example. I have a boat that references 3 operations but I have 5 operations that reference that boat. I wish to retrieve the same result as boat.operations. I obviously have my reasons for wanting do this directly in JPA. Performance mainly as I have a long structure of objects to go through to get there.